# How to separate 2 values returned by a function into 2 different variables C++

Tags: c++, function

The function that return the values is this

```
float calcVelocity(float xacceleration, float yacceleration,sf::Clock clock, float originalDistance){
    sf::Time time = clock.getElapsedTime(); //get current time and store in variable called time
    float xvelocity = xacceleration*time.asSeconds();
    float yvelocity = yacceleration*time.asSeconds();
    while (!(originalDistance + calcDisplacement(yacceleration, clock, originalDistance) <= 0)) {
        time = clock.getElapsedTime(); //get current time and store in variable called time
        xvelocity = xacceleration*time.asSeconds();//Calculates velocity from acceleration and time
        yvelocity = yacceleration*time.asSeconds();
        cout << xvelocity<<endl;//print velocity
        cout << yvelocity << endl;
        system("cls");//clear console
    }
    return xvelocity;
    return yvelocity;
}
```

I then want them to print as finalXvelocity = blah and finalYvelocity = blah after the while loop is finised. In the main code when I call the function and output the result, it prints both values together. E.g finalXvelocity = blahblah.

I was thinking I could separate the values returned into the main code and then print them using those but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) (via [`std::make_pair()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair)).

Comment: @BoBTFish: Write that up as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have more than one return value, since C++11 you can return them as a std::tuple. No need to explicit declare a data struct.

e.g.

```
tuple<float,float> calcVelocity(/*parameters*/) {
  // your code
  return make_tuple(xvelocity,yvelocity);
}
```

Outside the function you can access the values by:

```
tuple mytuple = calcVelocity(/*parameters*/);
float xvelocity = get<0>(my_tuple);
float yvelocity = get<1>(my_tuple);
```

For pre-C++11 std::pair is also an option for just 2 values. But in this case the struct solution is more explicit.

Comment: Plus one, this is a nice answer, although I will confess that I think that `std::tuple` is a scaled down version of the devil.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `struct`:

```
struct velocity
{
    float x_component; /*ToDo - do you really need a float*/
    float y_component;
};
```

This will be the most extensible option. You can extend to provide a constructor and other niceties such as computing the *speed*. Perhaps a `class` is more natural, where the data members are `private` by default.

Comment: I have an objection to declaring it as a class with private members, setters and getters. It would be equivalent to the struct in your answer, yet with a lot of boilerplate code pretending to be a good object-oriented design. Constructors for such data-structs are useless since C++11 with brace-initialization.